# Why when trying to connect using android studio java web server to my server on the pc i'm getting error?

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-studio

On my pc I'm running a web server. Then in my android device using my code in android studio I'm trying to connect to the pc web server on the network WiFi.

My android device is connected already to the network with WiFi.
I know my pc's IP address.

This is in the top of the `MainActivity`

```
private String[] ipaddresses = new String[]{
            "http://192.168.1.10:8098/?cmd=nothing",
            "http://10.0.0.1:8098/?cmd=nothing",
            "http://10.0.0.138:8098/?cmd=nothing"};
```

In the `onCreate`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();
        currentActivity = this;
        initTTS();
    }
```

Then the `addListenerOnButton();`

```
public void addListenerOnButton()
    {

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connecttoserverbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusTextView);

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)

                        {
                            counter = i;
                            try
                            {
                                response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                String err = e.toString();
                            }

                            if (response!=null)
                            {


                                try
                                {
                                    final String a = new String(response, "UTF-8");




                                    text.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            text.setText(a + " Oמ " + ipaddresses[counter]);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    iptouse = ipaddresses[i].substring(0,ipaddresses[i].lastIndexOf("=")+1);
                                    connectedtoipsuccess = true;
                                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("encoding exception");
                                }

                                Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("test1");
                                break;

                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }





                        }
                        counter = 0;
                        if (response == null)
                        {
                            text.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    text.setText("Connection Failed");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });

    }
```

Then last the Get method

```
private byte[] Get(String urlIn)
    {
        URL url = null;
        String urlStr = urlIn;
        if (urlIn!=null)
            urlStr=urlIn;

        try
        {
            url = new URL(urlStr);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try
        {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            byte[] buf=new byte[10*1024];
            int szRead = in.read(buf);
            byte[] bufOut;

            if (szRead==10*1024)
            {
                throw new AndroidRuntimeException("the returned data is bigger than 10*1024.. we don't handle it..");
            }
            else
            {
                bufOut = Arrays.copyOf(buf, szRead);
            }
            return bufOut;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (urlConnection!=null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

In my android device when running the program and clicking the button i'm getting error/exception:

```
05-13 08:03:56.055 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:623)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:198)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:687)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:541)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:147)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.web_server.webserver.MainActivity.Get(MainActivity.java:324)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.web_server.webserver.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:34)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.web_server.webserver.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:94)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-13 08:03:56.061 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-13 08:03:56.062 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
05-13 08:03:56.062 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:282)
05-13 08:03:56.062 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:608)
05-13 08:03:56.062 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:    ... 13 more
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:623)
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:198)
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:687)
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:541)
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:147)
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190)
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.web_server.webserver.MainActivity.Get(MainActivity.java:324)
05-13 08:03:56.063 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.web_server.webserver.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:34)
05-13 08:03:56.064 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.web_server.webserver.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:94)
05-13 08:03:56.064 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-13 08:03:56.064 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-13 08:03:56.064 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
05-13 08:03:56.064 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:282)
05-13 08:03:56.064 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:608)
05-13 08:03:56.064 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:    ... 13 more
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:623)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:198)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:687)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:541)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:147)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.web_server.webserver.MainActivity.Get(MainActivity.java:324)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.web_server.webserver.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:34)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at com.web_server.webserver.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:94)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-13 08:03:56.069 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-13 08:03:56.070 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
05-13 08:03:56.070 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:282)
05-13 08:03:56.070 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:608)
05-13 08:03:56.070 8930-12196/com.web_server.webserver W/System.err:    ... 13 more
```

Line 324 is:

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

Line 34:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

Line 94

```
response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);
```

Comment: Why are you using three ip's in a loop? You are not even telling which ip causes the trouble. Do you think we can see that?

Comment: 'String[] ipaddresses'. You are not putting ip addresses in them but url's. You write unreadable code in this way. It confused me already.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add this 3 lines to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```